# Moving the rendered template of a component in Angular 6 to directly under the body element?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component which is nested pretty deep in the HTML tree of components in an Angular 6 app. It has a part that is fixed and should fill the whole viewport. Unfortunately one of its ancestor elements has a transform applied to it, which causes the fixed position to fix relative to the transformed ancestor element instead of the viewport.

What is an Angular friendly way to move this fixed element to be a direct child of document.body, such that the lifecycle of the component still runs correctly and I am able to keep the component declaration in the hierarchy position it is currently in?

**Incase the question isn't clear -**

I want to go from this, where the element with id="fixed-backdrop" gets moved to a direct child of the body element so the transformed parent doesn't affect the fixed positioning, while still making sure the Angular component class of "some-child-component" can still access the element and clean it up on destroy:

```
<body>
   <app-root>
    <some-transformed-parent-component>
       <some-child-component>
           <div id="fixed-backdrop"></div>
       </some-child-component>
    </some-transformed-parent-component>
   </app-root>
</body>
```

Goal:

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <some-transformed-parent-component>
       <some-child-component>

       </some-child-component>
    </some-transformed-parent-component>
  </app-root>
    <!-- Still managed by some-child-component -->
    <div id="fixed-backdrop"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `<body>` tag should only be used in the index.html file and should only contain the selector for your app component.

Comment: @DeborahK The examples are supposed to represent the rendered html, In a normal non-angular situation, I'd removeChild from the component host  and document.body.appendChild the element, but I don't think that is Angular supported or at the very least a bad practice/code smell, so I am hoping there is an Angular specific way to move things around like this

Comment: Ah. I see what you meant. Does this article help? https://hackernoon.com/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6

Comment: @DeborahK Yeah, more so the fact that it linked to cdk portals. I need to look into that but looking at examples it looks like it does exactly this, and if google has implemented it it will be more robust that anything I can spin up in a few days. If you want to reference the cdk portal stuff in an answer I'll accept it.